# read successive frames OpenCV using cvQueryframe

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have a basic question in regards to cvQueryFrame() in OpenCV.

I have the following code:

```
IplImage *frame1,*frame2;
frame1 = cvQueryFrame(capture);
frame2 = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Now my question is: if `frame1` is a pointer to the first frame, is `frame2` a pointer to the 2nd frame? So will the two `cvQueryFrame()` calls read successive frames?

I thought I'd check myself first but the pointers `frame1`,`frame2` seem to have the same hex value. :s I just need to capture two frames at a time and then need to process them.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found from google that calling cvQueryFrame() twice returns the same pointer. now I am slightly confused. If i use call it only once in a while loop, the frames progress but not if i call it twice? Is there a easy way to grab two frames?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cvQueryFrame()` returns the pointer to OpenCV's "private" internal buffer which it always fills with the last grabbed frame.
If you want 2 frames you will need to cache a copy. Once you allocate (e.g. using `cvCloneImage()`) space for your previous frame, you can use `cvCopy()` to copy just the image data. Do *not* use `cvCloneImage()` inside the loop as that is very inefficient due to the internal memory allocations (and deallocations, otherwise you'll have memory leaks as well).

**Update:** the code will look something like this:

```
IplImage* currFrame = 0;
IplImage* prevFrame = 0;
CvCapture* cap = cvCaptureFromAVI("sample.avi");   
currFrame = cvQueryFrame( cap );

 // Clone the frame to have an identically sized and typed copy
prevFrame  = cvCloneImage( currFrame );

while(currFrame = cvQueryFrame( cap ))
{
    // process the video using currFrame and prevFrame...

    // ...


    // When done, overwrite prevFrame with current copy in preparation
    // for the next frame.
    cvCopy( currFrame , prevFrame); 
} 

cvReleaseImage( &img1 );
cvReleaseCapture( &cap );
```

**Note:** Often, you can avoid this "redundant" copying time by doing a conversion instead.
For example, say your display is in color, but your processing is in grayscale. You only need the 2 consecutive copies in grayscale. Since you will need to convert to grayscale anyway, you can do that directly from the captured frame thus avoiding the redundant `cvCopy()`. To save the previous frame you would just swap pointers between your 2 allocated grayscale images.

Comment: I understand your approach but have one question. if its advised that cvCloneImage() not to be used in a loop, how do you query the frame and then use cloneimage for the video. outside the loop it is useless because you will only get a single frame.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Will try to implement that and update this thread soon.

Answer (score 1):

Ok !

You have to make a copy of your frame.
frame1 = cvQueryFrame(capture); is a pointer as you said.

The code i found is :

```
IplImage* img1(null), img2(null);
CvCapture* cap = cvCaptureFromAVI("mavideo.avi");
img2 = cvQueryFrame( cap );
img1 = cvCloneImage( img2 ); // on alloue une nouvelle image

while( cvGrabFrame( cap ) )
{
    cvCopy( img2, img1 ); // copie de l'image, pas du pointeur
    img2 = cvRetrieveFrame( cap );
} 

cvReleaseCapture( &cap );
cvReleaseImage( &img1 );
```

You can replace the while by a waitkey or anything but if you do that use

```
img2 = cvQueryFrame( cap );
```

instead of

```
img2 = cvRetrieveFrame( cap );
```

cause you'll not have the

```
cvGrabFrame( cap )
```

anymore

I don't know if i'm clear so... i stay here ^^

Enjoy ;)

Laurent

Comment: Hey i understand this approach but I thought cvQueryFrame was just a wrapper for cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame together.

Comment: yes it is. ^^ its just if you change the while and erase the cvGrabFrame (like me) you couldnt use the cvRetrieveFrame correctly. its just a warning.

Comment: hey I posted an answer which for me at least is easier implementation. check it out.

Comment: Laurent, This is my final year master's project. I need to do real-time image processing on live video feed from a thermal IR camera. What about you?

Answer (score 1):

ok following from Laurent's answer: I believe the key is cvCloneImage(). cvCloneImage creates a new copy of the original image including the header, ROI, imageData etc. and then points frame2 to this new data.

Since cvQueryFrame is a wrapper for cvGrabFrame & cvRetrieveFrame together I didn't want to split up the functions, so with a small modification I can still use cvQueryFrame.

Below is my modified solution.

```
IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); //to read properties of frame.
IplImage *frame2 = NULL;
```

while (1){
    if(frame2) 
        frame = cvCloneImage(frame2); // copy image to allow grabbing next frame
    frame2 = cvQueryFrame(capture); //read next frame
    if(!frame2) break; //if frame cannot be read, EOF so break from loop
}

I hope you understand what I've done here. 
Feel free to ask any more questions.

Comment: @Atharval Can we use the same approach for deleting 1st frame from the second frame , util the video finish ? and than return the video ?

Comment: @Angel yes, now that you have two frames `frame` and `frame2` you can subtract them and store in `frame3`.