# How Copy frame to farme

Tags: c, opencv

How can a variable in one frame to another frame it is that kind of copy that is not a memory management problem

for example :

```
iplimage *frame = NULL;
iplimage *Temp_frame = NULL;

while(1) {
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

if( !frame ) break;

    Temp_frame=cvcloneimage(frame);

    cvreleaseImage(&Temp_frame);

    cvreleaseImage(&frame);
}
```

Error:

Unhandled exception at 0x75b39673 in open cv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0015f250..

Please help.

Comment: Please, edit your question: rewrite what you are actually asking (it is not readable at all at the moment), format code (including Uppercased names where necessary) and point to the line where exception comes from. There are much more chances that somebody will answer your question if it is easy to read.

Comment: RAM is filled. And should be empty. But when the frame is a copy of the application error occurs after 3 minutes,  how copy of iplimage ( not const)  to another iplimage  ????

Comment: See accepted answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567188/read-successive-frames-opencv-using-cvqueryframe) question. In short: you should call `cvCloneImage()` once _outside loop_ just to create image of same size and then use `cvCopy()` in the loop to copy only the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
iplimage *frame = NULL;
iplimage *Temp_frame = NULL;

while(1) 
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);    
    if (!frame) 
        break;

    if (!Temp_frame) // creates Temp_frame only once
        Temp_frame = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), frame->depth, frame->nChannels);    

    cvCopy(frame , Temp_frame, NULL);

    // DO NOT RELEASE the return of cvQueryFrame()!
    // I believe that's what crashing your application.
    //cvreleaseImage(&frame);
}

// Since the size of "frame" won't change, there's no need to to create/release 
// Temp_frame on every iteration of the loop. So we release it at the end:
cvReleaseImage(&Temp_frame);
```