# how to export 1x speed video from openCV + python

Tags: python, opencv, frame-rate

My current mode of recording video using opencv looks something like this

```
import cv    

capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(self.deviceID)
img_size=cv.GetSize(cv.QueryFrame(capture))

#create a writer object for the video
writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter(
        filename='temp.avi',
        fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
        fps=15,
        frame_size=img_size,
        is_color=1)

while True:
    #grab the frame
    img=cv.QueryFrame(capture)

    #write frame to video
    cv.WriteFrame(writer,img)


    #if 'Enter' or 'Esc' key is pressed, end video capture
    c = cv.WaitKey(7) % 0x100
    if c == 27 or c == 10:
        break
```

The problem is that I have to manually set the frames per second in advance. I've storing the images in a list and keeping track of how much time has elapsed, but that just exports a file with no frames:

```
import cv
import time

capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(self.deviceID)
img_size=cv.GetSize(cv.QueryFrame(capture))

imgList=[]

zero=time.time()
while True:
    #grab the frame
    img=cv.QueryFrame(capture)

    imgList.append(img)

    cv.ShowImage("Window1",img)

    #if 'Enter' or 'Esc' key is pressed, end video capture
    c = cv.WaitKey(7) % 0x100
    if c == 27 or c == 10:
        break
duration=time.time()-zero


framesPerSecond=len(imgList)/duration)
writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter(
        filename='temp.avi',
        fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
        fps=framesPerSecond,
        frame_size=img_size,
        is_color=1)

for i in imgList:
    cv.writeFrame(writer,i)
```

A little stucks. Any suggestions on an alternative method or tweaks to my existing code would be greatly helpful.

Comment: You are probably creating a video of a single frame, not a video without frames. Try changing `img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)` to `img = cv.QueryFrame(capture); dest = cv.CreateImage(img_size, img.depth, img.nChannels); cv.Copy(img, dst)` and then `imgList.append(dest)`. Now, why are you using this old API ?

Comment: I find for the python bindings there is much more documentation out there for cv than cv2. I'm starting to nudge a bit forward... i plan on rebuilding this in cv2 once I get it functioning.

Comment: So the part of the comment about making a copy of each frame didn't change anything in your final video ?

Comment: just finished implementing it. making the copy and appending it instead worked. Not particularly clear why, but it worked. Many thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567188/read-successive-frames-opencv-using-cvqueryframe for the reason on that. The documentation on these functions is not particularly good, it leads to believe that one could call `GrabFrame` many times and at a later time call `RetrieveFrame` the same amount of times, eliminating the need for these copies and also for increasing the fps calculated.