# using cvRetrieveFrame get strange image

Tags: opencv, avi, background-subtraction

I am reading a avi file, and do some background subtrcation work. The wierd thing is when I use `cvRetrieveFrame`, I got a strange image, like below:

origin:

[image]

cvRetrieveFrame returns:

[image]

I don't know what's the problem. Here is my code snippet.

```
CvCapture* readerAvi = cvCaptureFromAVI( filename.c_str() );
if(readerAvi == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "Could not open AVI file." << std::endl;
return 0;
}

// retrieve information about AVI file
cvQueryFrame(readerAvi); //....get some information, width, height, ....

// grad next frame from input video stream
if(!cvGrabFrame(readerAvi))
{         
    std::cerr << "Could not grab AVI frame." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}       
frame_data = cvRetrieveFrame(readerAvi);
```

Comment: At first sight it looks like you've got the red and blue channels swapped - i.e. BGR instead of RGB or vice versa.

Comment: @RogerRowland what about the offset? look at the image right part, it should be in the left.

Comment: I see - it looks like the frame has a header of a different size to expected, so it's maybe a pixel format problem or a codec issue. Can you post the code you use to display the image after `cvRetrieveFrame`?

Comment: I noticed you call `cvQueryFrame` first - this wraps `cvGrabFrame` and `cvRetrieveFrame` internally, so you'll skip a frame with this code. Remember that the data returned by `cvRetrieveFrame` is re-used for the next frame, so you have to `cvClone` it if you want a copy of that image.

Comment: Take a look at this related answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4568840/2065121

Comment: @RogerRowland I don't show the image. The second image is saved as a bmp fils from cvRetrieveFrame returns.